# Create listing with Google Shopping attributes using Bigcommerce API

Tags: bigcommerce, google-shopping

Is it possible to create listing with Google Shopping attributes using Bigcommerce API?

I have found only possibility to get Google Product Search Mappings:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products/googleproductsearch

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is not. The API documentation is correct in that the GPS (Google Product Shopping) fields are GET only at this time.